# Send message to multiple users in Protected Channel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the following code that contains info about one user to send read time message.

Question: Is there any way to send message to more 10 users my current code sends message to one user like this

```
return new PrivateChannel('SendMessageChannel.1');
```

**Event Class**

```
class SendMessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $Message;
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->Message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('SendMessageChannel.1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not wrong you are trying to create a group chat where multiple users can chat with each other in a single chat room.

What you want is not just up to the Echo implementation. It also requires database structure accordingly.

So I can give you the brief idea about how I did previously.

I have a `chatrooms` table which contains ids(in comma separated form) of all the users which are added to that room. In channel route, this how I'm checking that a specific user should allow to read a message or not:

```
Broadcast::channel('private-chat-room-{chatRoom}', function ($user, $chatRoom) {
    $chatRoom = App\Models\ChatRoom::find($chatRoom);
    if(in_array(auth()->user()->id, explode(',', $chatRoom->user_ids))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```